# English Syntax Rules Based on Word Choice

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, semantics, syntactic-analysis

I was reading the Wikipedia article on [Animacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy) and came across something I found to be very interesting:

> The higher animacy a referent has, the less preferable it is to use the preposition of for possession, as follows (this can also be interpreted in terms of alienable versus inalienable possession):
>
> *My face is correct*, while *the face of me* is not.
>
> *The man's face* and *the face of the man* are both correct, and the former is preferred.
>
> *The clock's face* and *the face of the clock* are both correct, and the latter is preferred.

It is really interesting to me that there are two different ways of writing the same thing, and the ideal way is based almost entirely on animacy.

Are there any other similar types of characteristics in the English language (where there are multiple ways of writing the same thing, and one becomes more "correct" based on a property of one of the words in the phrase)?

Also, is there a name for this field of study, or available resources for someone interested in learning more about this? I'm interested in this to help teach ESL students different things like this which native speakers innately know (having to do with the structure of a sentence), but don't realize they know.

Comment: It's called Linguistics. And most ESL teachers study it at some time.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. The reasons why we pick a certain construction over an equivalent in certain situations are indeed very interesting. One thing to consider here is that the construction *of mine, of my father's, of his* normally makes *of me, of my father, of him* impossible when it is supposed to express possession. This is not the case with **of the man's* or **of the clock's*, so your first category is not entirely comparable with the other two. There are also some other factors, so it's very complicated.

Comment: @JohnLawler I understand that it is Linguistics - I was more wondering if there was a specific sub branch of Linguistics that deals with these types of syntax properties.

Comment: It's what most of syntax is about. See, for instance, Beth Levin's _English Verb Classes and Alternations_ or Postal's _On Raising_.

Comment: @JohnLawler  "It's called Linguistics."  You might win a prize for the most said with the least words.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you very much, your second response was very helpful (especially the recommendation for Beth Levin's _English Verb Classes and Alternations_). Do you have any other recommended reading material like this which cover similar topics and/or have the same "dictionary" style to them?

Comment: I haven't seen anybody do the same job as Levin for non-cyclic rules; many of these are governed, too. The closest thing might be [Ross's dissertation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html). And there are lots of other kinds of cyclic rules, like [Equi and Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), which are governed by predicates. Many of the rules of English syntax can be found [briefly summarized here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf); there are a lot of them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about linguistics rather than English.

Comment: @JohnLawler These links are great - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @TimLymington: things get confusing for people if on "a question and answer site for _linguists_, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts." a _linguistic_ question is considered off-topic...

Comment: @oerkelens: Someone who cannot distinguish between a question about English and a question about languages in general probably is not a linguist. And I remain of the opinion that this question, though valuable, would be a better fit on Linguistics.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Passives and pseudopassives are also sensitive to animacy.

For passives, consider a situation in which a man walking his dog is killed.  If the killing is by a gunman (animate), then you can imagine, say, a newsreader opening a report on the killing with either of the following:

> A man walking his dog has been killed by gunman ...
>
> A gunman has killed a man walking his dog ...

If, however, the man was run down by a bus, the passive is strongly preferable:

> A man walking his dog has been killed by a bus ...
>
> ?? A bus has killed a man walking his dog ...

Pseudopassives are passives of verbs that take a prepositional complement, but not a true direct object.  To see the role that animacy plays in pseudopassives, consider:

> Napoleon slept in this bed
>
> The arrow quivered in his chest

The first of these, with an animate subject, completely straightforwardly admits passivization of the verb:

> This bed was slept in by Napoleon.

The second, with an inanimate subject, does not:

> ?? His chest was quivered in by the arrow.

A more minimal pair, highlighting the role of animacy, is:

> A bird/book flew across the room
>
> The room was flown across by a bird/??book

An animate flyer (*bird*) permits the verb to undergo pseudopassivization, but an inanimate one (*book*) does not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's why we tend to say the fly is on the wall, rather than the wall is supporting the fly. I wrote a piece about this recently which you can read [here](http://spblp.ru/ru/magazine/pdf/92/s/page-94).